# How to create 2 dimensional json object in chsarp

Tags: c#, json

We can write 1 dimensional json-object in csharp like this

```
var Obj = new { username = "Test", password = "TEST" };
```

How would you write the two dimensional json-object, something like

```
var Obj = new { username: {[username:"Test", password: "TEST"]}, key:{[Key1:"OK"]} };
```

Comment: You mean you want to create a nested member inside your JSON? I don't see anything two dimensional your example.

Comment: yah, you are right, nested members

Comment: `json` is not what you think it is.

Comment: You're creating an anonymous object. Where are you attempting to create a JSON?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov , yes anonymous object, actually I am not familiar to anonymous object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are creating is not actually a JSON object. It has nothing to do with JSON, though I can see why you thing it does based on the syntax. It is actually an [anonymous type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb397696.aspx).

You can nest these types inside each other, like so (translating your example):

```
var Obj = new 
{ 
    username = new 
    { 
        username = "Test", 
        password = "TEST" 
    }, 
    key = new 
    { 
        Key1 = "OK" 
    } 
};
```

Comment: I am so silly :), yes this is anonymous type. and you solved the problem.